# wxpython, call a class function from the other class

Tags: python, function, class, tabs, wxpython

I'd like to run the class function in Class TabTwo when Class TabOne Onclick function is activated.

```
import wx

class TabOne(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.button = wx.Button(self, 12, "Submit", wx.Point(300, 590))   
        wx.EVT_BUTTON(self, 12, self.OnClick)

    def OnClick(self, event):
        a = TabTwo.getTab2info()
        print a

class TabTwo(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.tb2name= wx.StaticText(self,-1, "The number of pay out years:", wx.Point(20, 190))
        self.tb2input=wx.TextCtrl(self, 31, "5",wx.Point(315, 190), wx.Size(150, -1))

    @classmethod
    def getTab2info(cls):
        TabTwo.PayoutYears = self.tb2input.GetValue()
        return(TabTwo.PayoutYears)

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Information", size=(1200, 700))

    # Create a panel and notebook (tabs holder)
        p = wx.Panel(self)
        nb = wx.Notebook(p)

    # Create the tab windows
        tab1 = TabOne(nb)
        tab2 = TabTwo(nb)

    # Add the windows to tabs and name them.
        nb.AddPage(tab1, "Input")
        nb.AddPage(tab2, "Model Paramters")

    # Set noteboook in a sizer to create the layout
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        p.SetSizer(sizer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    MainFrame().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I got the error message as below:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/a0266997/Documents/Casualty/tbs2.py", line 124, in OnClick3
>       a = TabTwo.getTab2info()
>     File "C:/Users/a0266997/Documents/Casualty/tbs2.py", line 224, in getTab2info
>       TabTwo.PayoutYears = self.tb2input.GetValue()
>   NameError: global name 'self' is not defined

Comment: There is no `self` in a class method. You have no object to refer to. It is, after all a _class_ method, not an _instance_ method. A class method cannot refer to the variables of any object. You could perhaps pass the  instance (the `self` variable) to the class method when you call it. But why does `getTab2info` need to be a class method anyway? Is there any reason it cannot be a normal method?

Comment: I am new to this.   If I change the function to instant method:                   def getTab2info():
        TabTwo.PayoutYears = self.tb2input.GetValue()
        return(TabTwo.PayoutYears)                I got error:  TypeError: unbound method getTab2info() must be called with TabTwo instance as first argument (got nothing instead).

Comment: If I change the line calling class TabTwo function to:   a = TabTwo().getTab2info()   I got error as below
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given). I'd appreciate any help

Comment: I think maybe you better explain exactly what you're hoping to achieve here. Calling that method is not an end, it's a means to an end. What's the actual objective here. Currently you have two separate notebook tabs, that need to know a lot about each other for some reason. I'm having trouble following the reasoning.

Comment: What I like to achieve is: when I click on "submit" button in TabOne, python will collect the user inputs on TabOne and TabTwo. I set up 2 tabs is because setting up all user inputs in one tab, the interface will be too big

Comment: Your two tabs are too dependent on each other, I think. Try moving that functionality into the wx.Frame instead. Let the tabs have variable names in the frame and then collect from there instead. You can use `self.GetParent()` to access the frame from the tabs, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Review the comments. There they give you the solution.

Here is your code fixed. I have deleted your comments and I have put some new ones:

```
import wx

class TabOne(wx.Panel):
    # We pass the main frame as the last parameter of the constructor
    def __init__(self, parent, mainFrame):
        # Call to superclass:
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        # Let's assign the main frame to a member variable of this class
        self._mainFrame = mainFrame
        self.button = wx.Button(self, 12, "Submit", wx.Point(300, 590))   
        wx.EVT_BUTTON(self, 12, self.OnClick)

    def OnClick(self, event):  
        # I use the main frame to access the instance of class TabTwo.      
        a = self._mainFrame.tab2.getTab2info()                
        print a

class TabTwo(wx.Panel):
    # We pass the main frame as the last parameter of the constructor
    def __init__(self, parent, mainFrame):
        # Call to superclass:
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        # Let's assign the main frame to a member variable of this class
        self._mainFrame = mainFrame

        self.tb2name= wx.StaticText(self,-1, "The number of pay out years:", wx.Point(20, 190))
        self.tb2input=wx.TextCtrl(self, 31, "5",wx.Point(315, 190), wx.Size(150, -1))

    def getTab2info(self):
        #payoutYears is local variable only used in this method.        
        payoutYears = self.tb2input.GetValue()
        return(payoutYears)

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Information", size=(1200, 700))
        p = wx.Panel(self)
        nb = wx.Notebook(p)
        self.tab1 = TabOne(nb, self)
        self.tab2 = TabTwo(nb, self)        
        nb.AddPage(self.tab1, "Input")
        nb.AddPage(self.tab2, "Model Paramters")
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        p.SetSizer(sizer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    MainFrame().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Good luck.